# impromptu.js and infieldlabel.js wont work together

Tags: javascript, impromptu

I'm using a simply modal dialog called Impromptu, and I'm also using a contact form that uses the infieldlabel.js -- however, in order for the Impromptu script to work, infieldlabel will not. in order for infieldlabel to work, I have to disable the impromptu script.

Any reason for this??

Comment: Have you tried debugging it? Your code throws JavaScript exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

You are loading **three** different versions of jQuery at the same time. If the two libraries depend on different incompatible versions, that could be your reason to why they're not working together.

Comment: so should I just limit it to the most recent version? or if I do that, will it stop other scripts from working?

Comment: I don't know. Look up which versions your libraries require, and if you're able to find a common version, use only that one.

Comment: I'm not sure. I'm giving up on it, I've been working on both scripts for the entire day now. I'm just going to put left padding on the form so that way the user can still enter information and be able to see it. :(  here's a link to what it looks like now [here](http://www.mcgehee.ace-onecomputers.com/)